# how to look up a a value from another datatable and display it in an unbound column of a bound datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorry, I tried to search for an answer but I'm having a really hard time translating the examples I've found into my own scenario.

I have an MS Access Database that has an "Employees" table with the following columns:

"Employee ID", "Name", "Middle", "Last", "Hire Date", "Fired Date".

Another Table "Work" that has the columns:

"Date", "Employee ID", "Activity", "Hours worked", "Department", "Shift", "Equipment Used",

A datagridview is bound to the "Work" table.
I call the FillbyDate() with a query made with the query editor at design time so only the entries for the specific date are loaded.

I would like to create an unbound column to display the name (NAME, MIDDLE, AND LAST) of the employee from the "Employees Table" using the employee Id to find it.

I'm completely new to coding with VB.Net, that might be reason why i don't understand or find the right examples. I would appreciate some sample code and the comments for each step to see how things are working.

Just as FYI i'm reading a couple of coding books:
Practical Database programming with VB.Net, Clearly Visual Basic 2010, Masterig MS Visual Basic 2010

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to create an SQL query that will [**join**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) the tables based on the Employee ID field and will filter the data based on the date field. The DataGridView will be binded to a DataTable which will be filled based on that SQL query.

Sample code :

```
Dim FilterStr1 As String = "03/01/2013"
Dim DBPathStr1 As String = "C:\db1.mdb"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SqlConnStr1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPathStr1 & ";"

    Dim SqlStr1 As String = <SQL>
                                SELECT
                                    W.[Date]
                                    ,W.[Employee ID]
                                    ,W.[Activity]
                                    ,W.[Hours worked]
                                    ,W.[Department]
                                    ,W.[Shift]
                                    ,W.[Equipment Used]
                                    ,E.[Name]
                                    ,E.[Middle]
                                    ,E.[Last]
                                FROM [Work] AS W
                                INNER JOIN [Employees] AS E
                                    ON W.[Employee ID] = E.[Employee ID]
                                WHERE W.[Date] = #<%= FilterStr1 %>#
                            </SQL>.Value

    Dim OleDBAdap1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlStr1, SqlConnStr1)
    Dim SqlDTable1 As New DataTable

    OleDBAdap1.Fill(SqlDTable1)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = SqlDTable1

    OleDBAdap1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

To use this code you will need to change the value of the variable `DBPathStr1` with the path of your MS Access Database and set a date value for the `FilterStr1` variable.

**EDIT**

The value of the `FilterStr1` variable can be assigned by using a DateTimePicker control. To do that you will need to add a DateTimePicker control on the form and add the following code.

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    FilterStr1 = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: So i wouldn't have to use a table adapter or dataset, etc? also how would i set the date value to a datetimepicker?

Comment: No it's not necessary to use a table adapter or dataset, you can just fill and use a datatable. For the DateTimePicker usage see the edit.

Comment: Would it be too hard to adapt your code to display the employees name on an unbound column in the datagridview when the user enters the employee ID only if the employee doesn't have a termination date?